# How do I create a test.check generator for a sequence of actions in a constrained order?

Tags: clojure, test.check

```
(require '[clojure.test.check.generators :as gen])

(def ACTIONS
  {:create-new-user #{}
   :edit-user #{:create-new-user}
   :create-new-board #{:create-new-user}
   :edit-board #{:create-new-board}
   :create-new-anonymous-comment #{:create-new-board}
   :create-new-signed-comment #{:create-new-board}
   :edit-comment-text #{:create-new-anonymous-comment :create-new-signed-comment}
   :edit-comment-text-and-flip-anonymity #{:create-new-anonymous-comment :create-new-signed-comment}
   :flip-anonymity #{:create-new-anonymous-comment :create-new-signed-comment}
   :vote-comment-up #{:create-new-anonymous-comment :create-new-signed-comment}
   :vote-comment-down #{:create-new-anonymous-comment :create-new-signed-comment}})

(def actions (-> ACTIONS keys vec gen/elements gen/vector))

(defn filter-actions-into-logical-order [as]
  (let [seen (atom #{})]
    (filter
     (fn [v]
       (let [required (get ACTIONS v)
             valid? (or (some? (some required @seen)) 
                        (and (empty? @seen) (= v :create-new-user)))]
         (when valid?
           (swap! seen conj v)
           true)))
     as)))

(def ordered-actions (gen/fmap #(-> % filter-actions-into-logical-order vec)  actions))
```

As an example of the two generators:

```
# (last (gen/sample actions 100))
[:edit-user :vote-comment-down :flip-anonymity :vote-comment-down :vote-comment-down :vote-comment-up :edit-user :create-new-anonymous-comment :edit-board :create-new-signed-comment :vote-comment-up :edit-comment-text-and-flip-anonymity :edit-user :create-new-signed-comment :edit-user :edit-user :vote-comment-down :edit-user :vote-comment-down :create-new-user :vote-comment-down :create-new-user :create-new-user :edit-comment-text-and-flip-anonymity :create-new-user :edit-comment-text-and-flip-anonymity :create-new-anonymous-comment :edit-comment-text :create-new-board :vote-comment-down :flip-anonymity :create-new-signed-comment :vote-comment-up :create-new-user :create-new-signed-comment :edit-user :create-new-user :create-new-board :vote-comment-down :create-new-board :create-new-board :create-new-board :edit-board :edit-comment-text-and-flip-anonymity :edit-user :edit-comment-text :create-new-signed-comment :vote-comment-up :edit-comment-text-and-flip-anonymity :flip-anonymity :create-new-anonymous-comment :create-new-anonymous-comment :edit-board :create-new-signed-comment :edit-comment-text-and-flip-anonymity :edit-board :vote-comment-up :edit-comment-text :create-new-board :edit-comment-text-and-flip-anonymity :create-new-board :vote-comment-down :edit-comment-text-and-flip-anonymity :vote-comment-up :create-new-user :vote-comment-up :edit-comment-text :edit-board :edit-comment-text-and-flip-anonymity :flip-anonymity :edit-board :create-new-anonymous-comment :flip-anonymity :create-new-signed-comment :edit-user :edit-comment-text-and-flip-anonymity :edit-comment-text :edit-comment-text :create-new-user :flip-anonymity :edit-user :vote-comment-up :edit-user :create-new-user :edit-comment-text :edit-comment-text :flip-anonymity :edit-comment-text :edit-board :flip-anonymity :edit-board :edit-comment-text :edit-user :create-new-user :flip-anonymity]


# (last (gen/sample ordered-actions 100))
[:create-new-user :edit-user :edit-user :create-new-board :edit-board :edit-user :create-new-anonymous-comment :edit-comment-text :edit-board :edit-user :edit-user :vote-comment-up :edit-comment-text :create-new-signed-comment :edit-comment-text :create-new-board :edit-comment-text :edit-comment-text :edit-comment-text :vote-comment-up :vote-comment-up :edit-board :edit-comment-text-and-flip-anonymity :create-new-signed-comment :create-new-anonymous-comment :create-new-signed-comment :edit-user :create-new-anonymous-comment :edit-board :create-new-board :create-new-anonymous-comment :create-new-board :flip-anonymity :create-new-anonymous-comment :edit-board :vote-comment-up :vote-comment-down :edit-board :edit-comment-text :edit-user :edit-comment-text :flip-anonymity :create-new-signed-comment :vote-comment-up :edit-comment-text-and-flip-anonymity :vote-comment-up :create-new-signed-comment :edit-comment-text :create-new-signed-comment :create-new-anonymous-comment :edit-board :create-new-anonymous-comment]
```

`ACTIONS` is a map where the key is the name of the action, and the value is the (OR based) dependency for that action. As an example, you must first `:create-new-user` before you can do anything, you must `:create-new-board` before you can `:edit-board`, and you must have at least one `:create-new-*-comment` before you can `:edit-comment-text`.

The code above seems to work, but it is ugly. 1) I don't like how `filter-actions-into-logical-order` code has to have a specific exception for `:create-new-user`. 2) I don't like that I am basically taking the list of random actions, and filtering it down until the actions make ordered sense.

I am wondering how others would generate a sequence of actions like this using test.check? Surely there must be a way to do so using only generators?

Comment: Probably you could move/copy this question to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

It's not too hard to do this with a recursive generator that uses `gen/bind` (e.g., first generate the size of your list of actions, then use recursion over that size with `gen/bind` so that you have the previously generated actions at each step). The big downside to this approach is that `gen/bind` works rather poorly with shrinking, and so you're likely to end up with long sequences of actions that can't shrink almost at all.

I'd really like to come up with something better for this.

Answer (score 1):

Well, `filter-into-logical-order` could arguably be cleaner with a switch to `reduce`

```
(defn filter-into-logical-order [as]
  (last (reduce
         (fn [[seen accepted-as] action]
           (let[needed (get ACTIONS action)]
             (if (or (empty? needed) (some seen needed))
               [(conj seen action) (conj accepted-as action)]
               [seen accepted-as]))
           )
         [#{} []]
         as)))
```

but that still puts out about 30% empty vectors for me and it's not a generator. I'm not sure the documented combinators actually support what you want, though. `gen/vector` does not appear to support handing a vector-in-construction to its inner generator so it can know what values are allowed, which is kinda the structure your requirements need.

Comment: Yeah, I have had trouble figuring out how you do things that have a dependency. Maybe I need to figure out how to write my own generators, rather than using composition of generators?

Comment: Might be. If the state monad is usable in the framework of `generators` you could maybe use that to make an `order-constrained-elements` base generator, but I'm not really sure how to add that. Or if there's a fitting point to flush the state between sequences available.